# Remapping links to a new page

Tags: links

We're wanting to replace an existing item/page in the content tree with another that uses a new template design but will have the same item name (there's a reason we can't use the template change option).

To ensure anything pointing to the existing page is remapped to the new item/page id we'd normally use the out of the box link remap (shown when deleting a page).

Is there a better way of going about this rather than getting to the point of deleting the old page? Just feels a bit risky and would rather update in advance. And also the volume of links is likely to be quite extensive, so doing it at the point of delete isn't great.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack exchange :) 

think that in your case when you know Field, new Item Id will be better to use Sitecore PowerShell scripts. 

Firstly you need to run a script that replaced old values with new Item Id then just remove the old item.

If my solution will appropriate for you then I will add it as an answer.

Comment: You could write SQL script which would replace `Value` column of Shared, Version and Unversioned Field tables just to replace old ID with new ID. That would be the fastest and easiest way. But it would need clearing caches. And as this may not be possible on CD servers, it may require apps to restart.

Comment: Thanks @VadimBirkos, that may be the way to go. I'll have a chat with the team and see about running a powershell. Wasn't sure if Sitecore might have a wizard for something like this.

Comment: @Andy added a response to your question. Hope that it will help you

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment - You can use the Sitecore PowerShell extension for your purpose.

The general order of actions will be like below:

1. Write a script that will take all items with reference to the old item that you would like to remove. [Documentation](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/) can be helpful for you.
2. In the same PS script loop items from #1 and replace there an old value in the reference field with the new item Id.
3. Then you can remove the old item if needs.

If you will see a popup with the suggestion that will be with links to the item then you need to re-check links to this item again (probably, issues with your PS script)

Ping me if you need any help with PS scripts.